# The menu bar is behaving irresponsive even with right media queries

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a website on wordpress with a theme named Appland.
Issue is the website is not behaving properly in terms of responsiveness.
A white space is added on the right end when used on smaller screens.
The problem appears to be because of the length of the menu bar using up more width than the screen width (reason unknown), however, i manually set the bar to 500px for smaller screen which made the bar smaller but the issue persisted. The viewport meta tag is present and here is a [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/n56si8)

Comment: please make a pen, need to see the code :)

Comment: I am not sure I can filter out the code from the WP site. Here is the site link though germishield.com

Comment: try adding width:100vw to <nav> it made the nav bar shrink to the width of the content but the space still remains, it can be a rendering issue on my browser, try it and let me know

Comment: Done that, but doesn't solve. the white space issue

Comment: The issue is with the footer widget that has email address which is going out of screen size. Removing the email from footer solves this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the footer widget.
The text was going out of the screen width due to incorrect width in small screens.
I set the width of footer widget section to auto which took the section lower rather than dividing the screen into two columns.
Also, another issue faced was the css after being updated was not being fetched by website.
This is due to the older version of css file being fetched.  This can be changed in the function `wp_enqueue_style`